# Permutation of students in a class

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many ways can 10 BS and 7 MS students be arranged in a line so that no two MS students may sit together?

My approach:
Total number of ways all 17 students can be arranged in a line is (17!)/(10!*7!) ---(A)
Now total number of ways the students can be arranged such that two MS students sit together is (16!)/(5!*10!)---(B)
Now the required answer is A-B.
Is the above approach correct?

Comment: Do you mean two *specific* MS students, or some two MS students? In neither case is $\frac{16!}{5!10!}$ right, and two specific would not do the job.  One form of the correct answer to the original problem is $\binom{11}{7}10!7!$.  There are many "no two type X people sit together" questions on MSE.

Comment: Its some two MS students.

Answer (score 3):

The standard approach is to arrange the $10$ BS students in $10!$ ways amongst themselves and then insert the $7$ MS students in the 11 gaps before after and between them in $\binom {11}{7}$ ways and finally multiply by the number of arrangements of the MS stidents amongst themselves in the chosen gaps. multiply the results.

Comment: Do you also want to multiply by the number of ways to put the MS students in the 7 gaps chosen?

Comment: @user84413 You're absolutely right! What a drop off....

Comment: Thanks  -  (I have done exactly the same thing many times.)